# Not annotated method overrides method annotated with @NonNullApi

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

When I implement the interface CrudRepository, InellyJ gives me the following warning on various functions and parameters:

`Not annotated method overrides method annotated with @NonNullApi`

But when I look into CrudRepository, I don't see any @NonNull annotation, so where does that warning come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package is annotated with `@NonNullApi`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/package-summary.html